# ceaser cipher decryption not working for first three characters

Tags: java

im working on ceaser cipher where i shift each character by 3 position

while encrypting

if input is 'abc'

output string should be 'def'

it should shift every character 3 times to the right

```
int encryptionCharIndex=(((i-97+3)%26)) +97;

int decryptionCharIndex=(((i-97-3)%26)) +97;
```

but decryption for the first three characters in the alphabet it is showing

wrong characters that is characters before a,

but it should be like

```
a = x
b = y
c = z
```

Comment: Potentially the issue is `-3 % 26` gives `-3` and not `23`

Comment: @ phflack ... if you edit the question.... "I am"... not keeping this weird "im" slang swirling around. And add the capitals and full stops too ;p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add another `26` in order to handle negative values (before the modulu):

```
int decryptionCharIndex = (((i - 97 + 26 - 3) % 26)) + 97
// Subtract 'a' -----------------^
// Add another 26 to handle negatives-^
// Decrypt --------------------------------^
```